# Attempting to get text inside an li where the type is

Tags: puppeteer

With the following html:

```
   <div class="borderTopWhite item-sub-details">
       <ul>
          <li>Sport: <a href="#">Baseball</a></li>
          <li>Team: 
             <a href="#">Philadelphia Phillies</a> 
          </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
```

My goal is to get the text of Team.  In the above example I would like to return Philadelphia Phillies.

My (failed) attempt returns empty object:

```
        const details = await  page.$$eval(
          '.item-sub-details ul li',
          els => els.map(el => el)
          )
```

Comment: Can you share your resource? First of all, your selector returns not only Philadelphia Phillies, but Sport li also. Second - you should get two objects by provided code, if you don't your elements can be placed in iframe or shadow-root. 
Also, they can be not rendered yet when you call `$$eval`.

Comment: Here is an example: https://marketplace.beckett.com/item/900/1988-as-donruss-team-book-178-carney-lansford_71067508 @Yaroslavm